# Firebase synchronize background job that writes documents to Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a background job that runs every minute to update documents.
If an update takes longer than a minute I need to skip the next background job.
What's the best way to synchronize this logic?

I currently have

```
export const pickWinnerBackgroundJob = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {
    const lock = await admin.firestore()
        .collection(`lock`)
        .doc(BG_JOB_LOCK_DOCUMENT_ID)
        .get();

    if (lock.exists && lock.data()?.locked == true) {
        return;
    }

    await admin.firestore()
        .collection(LOCK_COLLECTION_NAME)
        .doc(BG_JOB_LOCK_DOCUMENT_ID)
        .set({ locked: true })

    var promises: Promise<any>;
    // Add document update promises and execute job

    return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        return admin.firestore()
            .collection(LOCK_COLLECTION_NAME)
            .doc(BG_JOB_LOCK_DOCUMENT_ID)
            .set({ locked: false })
    });
});
```

Is this a valid approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach looks reasonable, but you'll have to look out for race conditions. Since you likely can't prevent them completely, you'll have to pick a strategy that fits best with your needs, so: either you may skip one minute too many when there's contention, or two instances may run in parallel occasionally.

Alternatively, you could [set the maximum number of instances](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances#setting_max_instances_limits) for this Cloud Function to 1, and not worry about it in code. It looks like the syntax in Firebase's wrapper would be:

```
functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').runWith({ maxInstances: 1 }).onRun(async (context) => {
```

Comment: Amazing, maxInstances is exactly what I needed, thank you

Comment: actually `Property 'runWith' does not exist on type 'ScheduleBuilder'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about that. I don't see any exception or requirements for that optoin though: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/98bf467aa436f7e27969a8ad3887abe0345f66d3/src/cloud-functions.ts#L516

Answer (score 0):

You can also use each function invocation to schedule the next one for a minute after the current one.  Can't ever over-run that way.  (You do need to make sure they keep running, so you may also need a watch-dog)